# Why before_save/after_save is not triggered when attribute updates to nil? And how to trigger it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

**Update:**

Ok. I have another way to describe this. I'm saving an item, and `Base.save` is called on this item and all of its children. And since some of them are not this items children anymore, because I've unchecked them, `save` is not called on them. It sounds a little bit clearer. But still it's the same question described with another words. Why if a record is updated (some weird way though) and it's parent_id is changed, rails don't make it like an update?

======================================================================

My items have many-to-one association with themselves. I want to create comments to items when item changes his parent item. And everything works fine when `item.superitem_id` changes from nil to some id, or from some id to another id. But nothing happens, when `item.superitem_id` changes from some id to nil.

In the first case log shows:

```
UPDATE "items" SET "superitem_id" = 3, "updated_at" = '2011-04-12 23:07:05.566609' WHERE "items"."id" = 5
```

And in the second one:

```
UPDATE "items" SET "superitem_id" = NULL WHERE "items"."superitem_id" = 3 AND "items"."id"
```

So. Item is definitely changed. But why it's not updated and before_save is not called?

Model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :generate_comments

  has_many :subitems, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => "superitem_id"
  belongs_to :superitem, :class_name => "Item"

  private
    def generate_comments
      @comment = self.comments.build(:content => "Test: #{self.superitem_id}")
      @comment.save
    end

end
```

View with checkboxes from "HABTM checkboxes" railscast:

```
<% for subitem in @potential_subitems %>
  <%= check_box_tag "item[subitem_ids][]", subitem.id, @item.subitems.include?(subitem) %>
<% end %>
```

And Controller:

```
def update
  params[:item][:subitem_ids] ||= []
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
end
```

Answer (score 3):

My wild guess is that on the 2nd case your *association is saved* (even though it's the same table) so rails doesn't see it as an update on "self". Check this post to force a callback on a belongs_to with "touch" :

["Before Save" callback on associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090900/before-save-callback-on-associations)

Comment: For Rails 4 and below, your callbacks must return `true`... in Rails 5, you must explicitly raise an exception if your callback fails, so the callback chain aborts.